# Cassandra restore from incremental backup files from multilple nodes

Tags: cassandra, backup, restore

I am also looking for incremental/point-in-time backup / restore solution.

I have three Cassandra nodes,I enabled incremental backup , and i tried copy one day's SSTable files from backups folder on one node to a new cassandra cluster /data folder, then it works, but i have three node, and the name on all three node are same, i dont' know how to restore the incremental backup files from all the three nodes.

You comments are really appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is to config new cluster with exact same node, and everything can work.

But if i want to replay the data with less nodes, like only one, so i have to take a complete snapshot ?